# How to resize my UML class diagram on MS Visio'07

Tags: uml, visio

How do i resize the class diagram in Visio? My operations have many parameters so the class diagram becomes too long. I need to resize the height of it,how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well..

**The short answer is**

DO NOT RESIZE IT.

**If still want to resize**

Check

--> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264676

--> http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/4a8a9688-7d11-466f-b809-828d6e9b4c11/  [Emely16 answer]

**And Here is the LONG ANSWER:**

**If you do a reverse engineering to your code [ from code to digram] to understand code base better**

> Well visual representation like UML  also shows some "problems"
>   visually. First it should give you a code smell about "something is
>   wrong with my code" [ it may show a real problem or just an false
>   alarm] Check it and ask yourself "Why i have so many parameters in my
>   methods".

**If you are designing your system [ not write the code yet ]**

You are at wrong direction. UML is a visual thinking tool. Change your model-class.

> But do not try to model every part of your software details with UML
>   before coding.Use UML for hard and tricky parts to explore alternative design, to better understand system that you will code.Only the  working code is the real model.

**And As A general Modeling Advice [ Short Answer ]**

Whether you are doing reverse engineering or use UML to explore difficult part of your design

> To make your diagrams simple, you may choose NOT to show method 
>   parameters : Even sometimes you may cose not to show also methods and attributes even some classes also.This is OK.

**AS A COMMON SENSE RULE**

Ask yourself, if I show method parameters, what benefit will I get?

**HUMANS ARE IRRATIONAL**

You may find yourself in a crazy working enviroment where QA team or Boss want so.
Explain them with a common sense why this is bad.

If they insist on it, and you have no choice, ask them to buy a UML modeling tools which are more easy to use. And give them complicated and unusefull diagrams since they want it. :-)